# JavaScript creating new Date from a string without changing timezone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert a date string into a date object without changing the timezone. Here is the standard behavior:

```
new Date ("2014-10-24T00:00:00")
```

result

```
Thu Oct 23 2014 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

I am able to reverse the timezone by getting the offset in minutes, multiplying it by 60,000, and then adding that to the new string date.

```
new Date(new Date("2014-10-24T00:00:00").getTime() + new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*60000)
```

This works, but it seems like there must be a better way that doesn't require created three date objects.

Comment: Thanks zerkms, that works great. I'll add it as the answer.

Comment: `new Date('2014-10-24 00:00:00')` returns *invalid date* in Safari and Firefox.

Comment: You're right. I'm using this on a website that needs to support IE9, and IE doesn't see this as a valid date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not** parse strings using the Date constructor. It calls *Date.parse* which, despite being standardised for one version of ISO 8601 strings in ES5, is still almost entirely implementation dependent.

> I'm trying to convert a date string into a date object without changing the timezone.

```
> new Date ("2014-10-24T00:00:00")
```

That string will be treated differently in different browsers. If you want it to be treated as UTC, then it is simple to parse yourself:

```
function parseISOAsUTC(s) {  
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[0],--b[1],b[2],b[3],b[4],b[5],(b[6]||0)));
}

console.log(parseISOAsUTC('2014-10-24T00:00:00').toISOString()); // 2014-10-24T00:00:00.000Z
```

Now you can be certain that the string will be treated as UTC in all browsers in use (including the 20% or so still using IE 8 and lower).

If, on the other hand, you want the string to be treated as a local time, then just remove the *Date.UTC* part:

```
function parseISOAsLocal(s) {  
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[0],--b[1],b[2],b[3],b[4],b[5],(b[6]||0));
}

console.log(parseISOAsLocal('2014-10-24T00:00:00')); // Fri 24 Oct 2014 00:00:00 <local timezone>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of zerkms's solution.

```
new Date("2014-10-24T00:00:00".replace('T', ' '))
```

result

```
Fri Oct 24 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

Comment: That's a great answer if you want a string that is treated as local in some browsers, UTC in others and *NaN* in the rest.

Comment: You're right, it works in Chrome, but I need something that works across the board. Thanks.